# NativeScript won't run local build from Sidekick

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, sidekick

I freshly installed Sidekick for NativeScript.
When I press "**Run on Device**" button application throws

> "Your system is not configured for local builds"

Weirdly running the app from cmd with **tsc run** command works perfectly and application compiles and even start on my device with no problem. This is probably something with Sidekick. I tried to reinstall app and even create fresh project. 
I'm running on Windows 10 using Android SDK 25 and have libraries on version 5.0

[image]

Did anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely because you havent set up your machine for local builds although Sidekick is supposed to help automate that.

Try this:
run `tns doctor` in your cmd at elevated permissions and select 
`configure for local build` when prompted or any of the options that appeal to you if you change your mind.

Comment: @Jakub you can mark my answer as complete if it worked for you